# Xcode: How do I make Xcode4.2 run on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: xcode, macos

I recently upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion and my Xcode4.2 stopped working. It complains about it's not for Mountain Lion. I also installed Xcode4.4. But I have an important project that works under Xcode4.2 but had issues with Xcode4.4.

Is there a way to make Xcode4.2 work under Mountain Lion???
I didn't find a version for Mountain Lion on Apple Developer website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find Xcode 4.2 for Mountain Lion is that there is no such version. In the past, people have used tricks to get older versions of Xcode to run on newer OSs—but, much like the tricks people have used to run older SDKs in newer versions of Xcode, etc., Apple has intentionally or accidentally broken every one of them.

It really isn't worth fighting them on this. If you can get your code working in 4.4, do so. If you can't, keep a Lion machine (or virtual machine) around to build it with.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.2 isn't supported on Mountain Lion. In fact, it's pretty old at this point, and it's not getting any younger. You're going to have to update your project to work with newer versions of Xcode at some point anyway -- why not take the time to do it now? Xcode 4.4 will let you deploy to systems going all the way back to 10.4.